# Open declaration in other window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I recently updated eclipse. Before, when I had my editor window split. I could keep my working files in the bottom part of the split and whenever I opened a declaration it would open the file in the top half of the window. Now though, files containing the declaration open in whatever window I'm opening them from. Is there any way to get back the other behavior?

Answer (score 1):

On the "bottom part of the split" there are the tabs "Problems" "Javadoc" "Declaration" and "Console". If you have the declaration tab selected, highlighting something in the other part of the split will open its declaration in the declaration tab. Leaving the declaraion tab open, or pulling it out of its section with "Problems" "javadoc" and "console" to have its own section of the screen could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry that I haven't looked at it sooner. I tried it, and it doesn't really do what I wanted. I realized, however, that treating all tabs to the right of my working tabs as disposable, more or less works.